# CORS, SQLite and JavaScript. Any way to access the actual database without a local server?

Tags: javascript, sqlite, cors

I just discovered the wonderful thing that SQLite is, and I'm trying to get it to work on a local HTML file without a server, just plain JavaScript.

The SQLite [wiki](https://github.com/kripken/sql.js/wiki/Load-a-database-from-the-server) states that the local database be 'get' via `XMLHttpRequest`

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', '/path/to/database.sqlite', true);
```

But I can't because it's a cross origin requests. I had similar issues in the bast trying to read CSV files, and I solved it by using a file input and then passing the file forward to be parsed.

I tried doing the same thing, instead of passing `/path/to/database.sqlite` just passing the actual file. But it doesn't work.

Is there anyway to make this work without a local server and without messing with the security rules of the browser?

@YarGnawh like this `C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --allow-access-from-files`? I still get the same `XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/BOVESPA2014.sqlite. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.`

Comment: try running chrome using the ```--allow-access-from-files flag```

Comment: No that i know. Maybe using an insecure browser. If you give up, run a cheap development web server is not that hard: python -m SimplHTTPServer or python3 -m http.server

Comment: @YarGnawh like this `C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --allow-access-from-files`? I still get the same `XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/BOVESPA2014.sqlite. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.`

Comment: hmm double check by going to ```chrome://version```. i think on windows you need to restart all instances of Chrome.exe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welp, the best solution I've found was to simply use nw.